# Adding Angular material Menu to each row in Angular Material Table using more button at the end of a sticky table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a sticky table that I want to add `more_vert button` toggle to but I'm unable to achieve this because I don't know how to distinguish each `drop down menu list` from each other.

[image: Example of UI I want to see on click]

This table is a list of user data from a REST API the Menu for each row should display:
`- delete user`
`- edit user profile`
when I click the `more button`

I have followed the documentation for Material Menus and Sticky Table up till this point but each time I click the button to display the drop down on any row

```
     <ng-container matColumnDef="actions" stickyEnd>
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> </th>                  
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> 
            <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="user.user_id" aria-label="">
                <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-menu #appMenu="user.user_id">
              <button mat-menu-item>Delete</button>
              <button mat-menu-item>Edit</button>
            </mat-menu>  
        </td>
     </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing wrong menu.

```
[matMenuTriggerFor]="user.user_id"
```

should be

```
[matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this:

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-name="name">
    <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Log off {{name}}</button>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>

<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" [matMenuTriggerData]="{name: 'Sally'}">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>

<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" [matMenuTriggerData]="{name: 'Bob'}">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
```

[More info he](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview)

Answer (score 0):

```
 </table>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="menu" [sticky]="true">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="selectedElement = element"
        aria-label="menu options button with a vertical three dot icon">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
</mat-paginator>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="edit()">
    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
    <span>Edit</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="delete()">
    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    <span>Delete</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class YourComponent {

  edit() {
    console.log('edit =>', this.selectedElement)
  }
}
```

I find the `matMenuTriggerData` throws an error when the app tries to run, and using a variable `selectedElement` on the menu click event works fine for both displaying data on the menu and passing data to a function for processing.